# I have installed MiPCSuite through Wine and uninstalled with UninstallMiPCSuite but icons are left in Menu

Tags: 20.04, wine, uninstall, menu, software-uninstall

I have installed MiPCSuite through Wine and uninstalled with UninstallMiPCSuite but icons are left in Menu.
After launching icon it shows:

`Failed to launch "MiPCSuit"`

and sends me path to that place where it was installed.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my PC and Icons disapeared by themselves.